# can we retrieve data from firebase having null value in a specific child and put in recyclerview

Tags: android

I want to receive all those post having 0 comments then i want to put that data in a recyclerview ? how to do that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object object;
  List<Object> listObject=new Arraylist();
```

Add check if

`object=null`  then `object =new Object()` ,Initialize that Object and add it in `List.`like`listObject.add(object)`

and then pass it to Adapter. then add `null` checks in Your `custom Adapter` that if `Objects Attributes` are `null` just show `empty` view.!

```
 if (listObject!= null) {
            CustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(listObject, context);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesCustomAdapter);
                CustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```